# How to Use Firebase with Nativescript-Vue?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I've been trying to implement just a simple Firebase fetch since November. At this point, I wish I'd just created a new Rails api; it would have been faster.
But everyone insists Firebase is Oh So Simple.

In app.js,

```
import firebase from 'nativescript-plugin-firebase';
```

That part seems OK.
Instructions are all over the place after that.
The plugin's ReadMe suggests an initialization:

```
firebase.init({
  // Optionally pass in properties for database, authentication and cloud messaging,
  // see their respective docs.
}).then(
    function () {
      console.log("firebase.init done");
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
    }
);
```

Several others have insisted that the init code is unnecessary. It does run without errors, but the code he gives after that produces nothing. Also,

```
const db = firebase.firestore;
const UserStatusCollection = db.collection("UserStatus"); 
UserStatusCollection.get();
```

produce an empty object {}.

Here's my Firebase collection:
[image: Here's my Firebase collection.]

If I wrap the firebase call in async/await (and no one is showing it as this complicated),

```
async function getFireStoreData() {
  try {
    let result = await this.UserStatusCollection.get();
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.error(
      "UserStatusCollection.get()" + error
    );
  }
}
```

And call that

```
let temp2 = getFireStoreData();
console.log("temp2:" + temp2);
```

All I ever get is an object promise.

As I said, I wish I had just built up a new Rails API and had a far simpler life since November.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getFireStoreData` method is asynchronous and you're not `await`ing it. That is probably the reason why you're getting a promise back. Try to `await getFireStoreData()`. See if that works.

Since it's also a promise, you can try to use `.then`.

```js
getFireStoreData().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that gets a "Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function (68:12)
[20-02-21 07:53:49.471] (CLI)   let temp2 = await getFireStoreData();

Comment: Oh wait, my bad let me edit my answer. When using `.then`, you do not to use await. Read more about promises here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: OK!! Add () above, and it finally gives me this: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Comment: But I'm not seeing any connection issues.

Comment: You have to setup a service account or use the default one provided within each project on GCP to connect to firebase. On GCP navigate to IAM & Admin > Service Accounts. Also, check firebase quickstart guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Comment: Ha, well, now I can't get any device logging at all in Nativescript Sidekick. But, yes, I hadn't checked some box on Google Cloud Platform (who knew), so maybe that was it all along.

Comment: Now "UserStatusCollection.get()Missing or insufficient permissions."

Comment: OK, modified the Database Rules so it's in test mode. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#secure_your_data) Now I'm at least getting metadata. Thanks!